# How to make Automator service that enters highlighted text into Chrome address bar?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm trying to make an Automator Quick Action that will show up in the right click menu under Services that will take the highlighted text and put it in a new tab in Chrome.

Looking at various other posts, I attempted this AppleScript, but it doesn't work:

```
on run {input, parameters}
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set myTab to make new tab at end of tabs of window 1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Google Chrome"
            set value to input
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
end run
```

I can get it to work for a URL, but I want this to work for non-URLs too (and just perform the default Chrome behavior with that text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

On the day this answer was originally posted, this worked with the then current version of **Google Chrome**.

As is typical with software updates they break *code* that worked in previous versions.

As of the date of this update and testing with the latest release of **Google Chrome** Version 90.0.4430.93 (Official Build) (x86_64), you need to add a `toolbar 1 of ¬` in between the two `group 1 of ¬` to update the *code* to work with this latest release of **Google Chrome**.

---

**Original Answer**

Not sure why you need this when you can *select text*, then *right-click* and select **Search Google for “$selected_text”** which essentially does the same thing as you're trying to do with a **Quick Action** *service*.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* does what you're looking to do:

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
        if (count window) is equal to 0 then make new window
        make new tab at end of tabs of window 1
    end tell
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events"
        set value of ¬
            text field 1 of ¬
            group 1 of ¬
            group 1 of ¬
            window 1 of ¬
            application process "Google Chrome" to ¬
            input as text
        key code 36
    end tell
end run
```

---

Note that in order for this **Quick Action** *service* to work, **Google Chrome** and any other *application* you trigger the *service* from needs to be added to: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**

Additionally, **Google Chrome** needs to allow **System Events** under: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Automation**

[image: Automator Quick Action]

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try this out soon. Regarding why I want this, I should have clarified I intent to use this menu item from other apps that don’t have a way to open a Google search from highlighted text.

Comment: @Liron Yahdav, After reading your comment, that changes things, and I'd _code_ it differently. Are you using **Google Chrome** as your _search engine_ in **Google Chrome**, or some other _search engine_? Also, is **Google Chrome** your _default_ **browser**?

Comment: I just tried the AppleScript above and it almost works, except it triggers the enter key in the current app I have focused instead of in Chrome. I have Chrome as my default browser but I don't have Google as my search engine for the address bar. I'd like the script to use the search engine I have configured in Chrome, so your script would work correctly if it triggered the enter key in Chrome.

Comment: @Liron Yahdav, Which _search engine_ are you using?

Comment: @Liron Yahdav, I've updated the answer; however, it could be _coded_ better if you'd tell me which _search engine_ are you using.

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks like this works! The reason I don't think this can depend on my search engine is because I use this sometimes not to do a search but to open certain URL schemes that other apps don't properly hyperlink. For example, I use One Note for note taking and I use Things for task management. I sometimes link a One Note note from Things which is of the form "onenote:some_identifier". Things doesn't hyperlink this, but when I paste that link into Chrome's address bar it opens up correctly in One Note.

Comment: At some point this script broke. Now it gives error: The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “System Events got an error: Can’t get group 1 of group 1 of window 1 of application process "Google Chrome". Invalid index.”

Comment: @Liron Yahdav, Testing with the latest, as of today, **Google Chrome**, Version 90.0.4430.93 (Official Build) (x86_64), you need to add a `toolbar 1 of ¬` in between the two: `group 1 of ¬`